# View logs for all docker containers simultaneously

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I currently use docker for my backend, and when I first start them up with

```
docker-compose up
```

I get log outputs of all 4 dockers at once, so I can see how they are interacting with each other when a request comes in. Looking like this, one request going from nginx to couchdb

[image: http://i.imgur.com/E4GQ43F.png]

The issue is now that I am running on GCE with load balancing, when a new VM spins up, it auto starts the dockers and runs normally, I would like to be able to access a load balanced VM and view the live logs, but I can not get docker to allow me this style, when I use logs, it gives me normal all white font with no label of where it came from.

Using

```
docker events
```

does nothing, it won't return any info.

tldr; what is the best way to obtain a view, same as the log output you get when running "docker-compose up"

Comment: `docker events` is not what you are looking for. It returns a stream of docker engine events such as creating, starting, stopping and deleting containers (and more). `docker events` does not handle the logs from within each container. 

You could try making a small application that uses the docker remote api: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/api/docker_remote_api_v1.23/#get-container-logs. Or you could use one of the may tools already available for collecting docker logs: https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/logging/overview/.

Comment: @JamesStewy it just seems like there should be a easy way to just enable the logging, same as during start up.
May have to look into other logging options.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

If using docker-compose, you use

```
docker-compose logs --tail=0 --follow
```

instead of

```
docker logs --tail=0 --follow
```

This will get the output I was originally looking for.

Comment: But that asks for the docker-compose.yml, I have 4 of them and want to attach to them all...

Comment: @phazei why not put all your docker info in one docker-compose.yml?

Comment: If you find this not outputting expected result (eg. command exits and doesn't follow or displays very outdated log entries) check if you're using Docker projects, ie. using the -p flag to start the containers. If you use -p to start them you need to add -p to your logs command: docker-compose -p <project name> logs --tail 10 --follow

Comment: @Noland's comment about `-p` is particularly important when you are trying to run this command remotely, when your local folder may not match the project name. `docker -H ssh://user@host compose -p <project name> logs --tail=0 -f`

Answer (score 73):

You can see the logs for all running containers with

```
docker ps -q | xargs -L 1 docker logs
```

This may work with the `--follow` too if xargs is ran with `-P <count>`, where the count is higher than the number of running containers (thx @kisna for the example):

```
docker ps -q | xargs -L 1 -P `docker ps | wc -l` docker logs --since 30s -f
```

Comment: Is following multiple container logs something like: 
`docker ps -q | xargs -L 1 -P \`docker ps | wc -l\` docker logs --since 30s -f`

Answer (score 21):

I use a variation of this to live tail (--follow) all logs and indicate which log is tailing at the time. This bash includes both stdout and stderr.  Note you may need to purge the /tmp dir of *.{log,err} afterwards.

```
for c in $(docker ps -a --format="{{.Names}}")
do
       docker logs -f $c > /tmp/$c.log 2> /tmp/$c.err &
done
tail -f /tmp/*.{log,err}
```

Hope this helps.  Logging has become so problematic these days, and other get-off-my-lawn old man rants...

Comment: This script is awesome and really made my day. I can only recommend using it! +1 for the simplicity

Answer (score 9):

## Try "watch"

Here's a quick and dirty multitail/xtail for docker containers.

```bash
watch 'docker ps --format "{{.Names}}" | sort | xargs --verbose --max-args=1 -- docker logs --tail=8 --timestamps'
```

How this works:

- `watch` to run every few seconds

  - `docker ps --format "{{.Names}}"` to get the names of all running containers
  - `sort` to sort them
  - `xargs` to give these names to `docker logs`:

    - `docker logs` to print the actual logs

Adjust parameter "--tail=8" as needed so that everything still fits on one screen.

The "xargs" methods listed above (in another user's answer) will stop working as containers are stopped and restarted. This "watch" method here does not have that problem. (But it's not great either.)

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Docker Swarm, you can find your services by

```
docker service ls
```

Grap the id, and then run

```
docker service logs $ID -f
```

if the service is defined with tty: true, then you must run with the --raw flag. Notice, this wont tell you which container is giving the outputted log entry.

Comment: this only shows the logs for one service :/

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the last process stays in foreground.

```
(trap 'kill 0' SIGINT; docker logs -f container1 & docker logs -f container2 & docker logs -f container3)
```